# injecting element using the document.getElementById is not working in Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I have written a small javascript code and now need to inject the result into my HTML. I have inspected the windows element and even copied the specific selector for that element but it still doesn't inject the answer into it. I am trying to insert it into the span tag in the HTML code.

```js
const str = new Date().toLocaleString('en-US', { timeZone: 'Asia/Jakarta' });
console.log(str);

document.getElementById('#us').textContent = str
```

```html
<div class="header-button-item js-item-menu">
    <i class="zmdi zmdi-settings"></i>
    <div class="setting-dropdown js-dropdown">
        <div class="account-dropdown__body">
            <div class="account-dropdown__item">
                <a href="#"><i class="zmdi zmdi-email"></i>America Time&nbsp;&nbsp; - <span id="us"></span></a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: `document.getElementById('#us')` - you don't want the hash, `getElementById` takes just the ID itself. Make it `document.getElementById('us')`

Comment: Or use `document.querySelector('#us')` instead, which uses CSS selectors.

Comment: Further to Robin's comment, when you would want the hash in the selector is when you're using a function that expects CSS selectors, rather than a text string holding the ID. `document.querySelector` and `document.querySelectorAll` each expect the hash or dot notation used by css `#ids` or `.classes`

Answer (score 0):

You could try this:

```js
const str = new Date().toLocaleString('en-US', { timeZone: 'Asia/Jakarta' });
console.log(str);

document.getElementById('us').innerHTML = str
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to you all, I was able to solve it after going through all the comments.

my mistake was using the # together with the getElementById. So, I had to remove the # which then made it work well.

But if you need to use the # then you can go with something like getSelector.

```
document.getElementById('us').textContent = us_time 

or

document.getSelector('#us').textContent = us_time
```

Comment: `getSelector` is not a thing in JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

You're getting confused with `querySelector`.

```js
const str = new Date().toLocaleString('en-US', { timeZone: 'Asia/Jakarta' });
console.log(str);

document.querySelector('#us').textContent = str
```

```html
<div class="header-button-item js-item-menu">
    <i class="zmdi zmdi-settings"></i>
    <div class="setting-dropdown js-dropdown">
        <div class="account-dropdown__body">
            <div class="account-dropdown__item">
                <a href="#"><i class="zmdi zmdi-email"></i>America Time&nbsp;&nbsp; - <span id="us"></span></a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```